# Auto adjusting decimal Format places as the input format in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, formatting, format, decimal

I am searching for a solution to use a decimal Format places to be as a variable depend on the edittext formating.

Example:

if the input is 2 digits after the dot (100.21)

the text vew will use same format DecimalFormat("#,###.##")

if the input is 4 digits (100.2135)

the textview will use same format (DecimalFormat("#,###.####"))

and so on.

so the formatting will change as per the input formatting.

Comment: Is this for parsing, or formatting? What type is your input?

Comment: Formating. all inputs are numbers. what i want is the formatting must be changeable based on the input format.  ex1:  input = ###.##   | result = ###.##    ex2: input = ###.###  | result = ###.###

Answer (score 0):

`#` pattern character shows zero as absent, so `"#,###.####"` pattern will work for both cases:

```kotlin
import java.text.DecimalFormat

fun main() {
    val format = DecimalFormat("#,###.####")
    println(format.format(100.2135)) //100.2135
    println(format.format(100.21))   //100.21
}
```

In Kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/j0PveSblv

Comment: Thank you for your comment. but when I use calculating for two input numbers the result all the time will be 6 or 10 digits so if I use the formating you mentioned it "#,###.####" it will always show 4 digits after the dot

so if I input 3 digits after dot like (100.123)
the result will be same format 3 digits and will not exceed that

 or input is 5 digits after dot like (100.12345)
the result will be same format 5 digits and will not exceed that

is there any class or textwatcher can get the digits after the dicamle place from the edittext and change format ?

Comment: You don't need to change the format. Just set meaningful maximum fractions digits (either via pattern or via [setMaximumFractionDigits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)) method). Ultimately, you may set is as infinite (in JVM terms)  `DecimalFormat("#,###.####").apply { maximumFractionDigits = Int.MAX_VALUE }`.

Comment: Thank you, what i want is the result format will be exactly as the input. if input has 2 digits after the dot the result will use this format #,###.##.     if the input has 5 digits the result use this format #,###.#####   no less or more digits